# Adding excel UserForm data from specific cell

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to VBA and I am creating a customer data base in excel 2010 VBA. I have entered some values in excel sheet from A1 to C50, however from D4 to G50 is empty. When ever I try to enter the data using UserForm it adds the data to D51, E51, F51 and G51, but I want the data to be entered from D4, E4, F4 and G4 then so on again to the next row. Please help!

Here's the code:

```
Private Sub Cmdcreate_Click()

Dim iRow As Long

Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Worksheets("My.Sheet")

'''find  first empty row in database

''iRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1)

''  .End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

'revised code to avoid problems with Excel tables in newer versions

iRow = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _

    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 1


'check for a Name

If Trim(Me.TextBox1.Value) = "" Then

  Exit Sub

End If

'copy the data to the database

ws.Cells(iRow, 5).Value = ComboBox1.Value

ws.Cells(iRow, 6).Value = TextBox1.Value

ws.Cells(iRow, 7).Value = TextBox2.Value

'clear the data

TextBox1.Value = ""

TextBox2.Value = ""

ComboBox1.Value = ""

If ComboBox1.Value = True Then Cells(iRow, 5).Value = ComboBox1

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I think with the below code you are searchin whole worksheet for any value entered to cell and find function finds the value in A50 cell and stores the row as 50. That is why your other code starts from 51.

```
iRow = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _

SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 1
```

If you want to stick with find function you can change "cells" to a range which only will include column D. Otherwise your can use below code to identify last row

```
iRow = ws.range("D1").End(xlDown).Row
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. However I tried to use the code you provided but does not seems to work, can you please help me in sending the entire code. Please!

Comment: After researching many forums I found the code but there is some problem with the code as it is not adding the data from the top column and row, the data is added from 4th row. Here is the link to the excel sheet. [URL="https://www.dropbox.com/s/r31u9nx3cf22fem/CRM.xlsm?dl=0"]                                                                                                          Please help.

Comment: hi, can you please change    range("D1") to     range("D:D") and try? I do not have an excel right now that is why I can not try it.